# How to update absolute URLs for media files for a whole site at once?

Tags: php, html, css

I have moved a whole site to a new domain.  However, some of the `<img src>` urls are absolute and are no longer pointing to the files in the correct 
(new domain) location.  The relative URLs are working, since the file structure is the same as the original domain.  How can I redirect the URLs for the media files in one place for all the page files?

I have tried to set redirects in the `.htaccess` file but no luck.

Here is the most current version of the redirect I tried to use, but it seems to only works for page urls, not the media absolute urls in the body of the pages:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am looking for detailed instruction on where to put code etc. to redirect all of the absolute URLs in my site.  I am a rookie, so please be clear and kind.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. You should really consider to manually change each URL and use relative path for them now you know that it can be a source of trouble :)

Comment: Yea, I totally agree that relative paths are the way to go. I didn't develop this site, it's just what it is.  However, there are hundreds of files in the site and manually updating would be a last resort, it it's truly impossible.  Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: If all pages are flat files (like .html) then consider to use an editor to do the job. Open Notepad++ and go to `Search > Find in files`. Under `Find what`, enter the absolute part of the url. Under `Replace with`, enter nothing. Under `Directory`, choose the directory with all .html files and then hit the `Replace in files` button.

Comment: Bron, so the only way to achieve this to do it manually?

Comment: To be able to do this using .htaccess, you would need to still have access to the old domain. Plus it of course slows things down if every client needs to make a request to the old address first, only to be then redirected to the new one. If at all possible, you should fix this by replacing the wrong URLs in your code.

Comment: Misorude, ok, is there an easy way to change the urls at once in all files on the site? There are hundreds of files.

Answer (score -1):

separate the files in sizable chunks based on your pc's capabilities into folders and open them all in a text editor - search and replace, then go from there. Let me know if this helps or if I am completely off my rocker. : )

Comment: Anthony, so I can do search and replace for all files in a folder at once?

Comment: well im not sure if it's still a thing but that's what I did years ago on microsoft frontpage, opened 100 files at once and search and replaced every open document within the editor. You might be able to do this in dreamweaver or phpstorm, not sure.